# how to change zend framework default home page

Tags: zend-framework

I want to change default home page of zend framework which is application/views/index/index.phtml, to another view.
welcome all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not only change the view script to render, but change the "target" (means: module/controller/action). If you look at [the Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#manual-container) , there are options for the configuration (usually application.ini) to set this values

Comment: Thank you. I did it by adding resources.frontController.defaultControllerName="site" to application.ini.