# zend is not working properly

Tags: zend-framework

I have created a zend project. When I type this
 url : `http://localhost/test/public`

It gives "View script for controller Index and script/action name index"

But I don't know why. Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: -1 no basic research accomplished!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What were you expecting as an output ? It is so because it is the default controller/action that gets executed. [Change default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230647/how-to-change-zend-framework-default-home-page)